# Transition on hover in IE11 seems to have infinite duration

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I'm having a problem with getting a transition to work on the following page in IE11: http://www.polygongroup.com/be/ons-team/ .

On hover it should transition background color and transform over 120ms. This works in Firefox, Chrome and Edge. In IE11 it doesn't.

If I remove the transition-duration property the background color and transform switch on hover right away - so these properties are fine. The border around the li does change color, so hover state is definitely triggered. The IE developer tools also show the correct property values. It's like transition duration is somehow infinitely long.

It probably is something stupid, but I can't see it.

Relevant excerpts from the code:

```
<ul class="team-lijst">
    <li><img src="http://www.polygongroup.com/be/files/2015/07/sarah_driesen.jpg" alt="sarah driesen"  title="" />
    <p>Sarah Driesen<br />
        Sales en Marketing<br />
        <a href="mailto:sarah.driesen@polygongroup.com">sarah.driesen@polygongroup.com</a></p>
    </li>
```

Css:

```
<style type="text/css">
    ul.team-lijst {list-style-type: none; margin: 0; padding: 0;}
    ul.team-lijst>li {width: 200px; height: 200px; float: left; margin: 10px;position:relative;border-radius: 5px;border:1px solid #eee;overflow:hidden;}
    ul.team-lijst>li>img {width: 200px; height: 200px; position: absolute;left:0px;top:0px;}
    ul.team-lijst>li>p{font-size: 13px; line-height: 1.4; display:block; margin: 0; padding: 1px 5px 0px 5px;width: 200px;box-sizing:border-box; height: auto; position: absolute;left:0px; bottom: 0px;transform: translateY(16px); background-color:rgba(255,255,255,0.6);text-overflow: ellipsis;overflow:hidden;transition-duration: 120ms;-webkit-transition-duration: 120ms;}
    ul.team-lijst>li>p:first-line{font-size: 14px;font-weight:bold; }
    ul.team-lijst>li>p>a{font-size: 13px; }
    ul.team-lijst>li:hover{border-color:#2980b9}
    ul.team-lijst>li:hover>p{transform: translateY(0px); color:#fff;background-color:rgba(41,128,185,1.0);}
    ul.team-lijst>li:hover>p>a{color:#fff;text-decoration: underline;}</style>
```

Comment: I've tested your URL in IE11 but there's no effect as its showing on FF OR Chrome.
Have you used all possible cross browser compatibility CSS for all the effects you used?

Comment: Could you please post the relevant code? You can't expect us to plow through all the files and code to find those (probably) two or three faulty lines of code.

Comment: @vivekkupadhyay : transition-duration should be supported from IE10 up. -ms-transition-duration makes no difference. IE9 works well because it does not support transitions.

Comment: I notice there is no actual `transition-property` set...could that be it?

Comment: Setting `transition-property: all;` on `ul.team-lijst > li > p` changes nothing. Setting `transition-property: none;` is equivalent to elimination the transition altogether.